# Mongoengine Error while adding data to the database

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoengine

I have just started using mongoengine, I referred to the tutorials given at http://docs.mongoengine.org/tutorial.html I am getting an error when I am trying to add Post data to the database

```
mongoengine.errors.ValidationError: ValidationError (Post.TextPost:None) (A ReferenceField only accepts DBRef, LazyReference, ObjectId or documents: ['author']
```

I have added the screenshots of the files.

[The main app.py file and the directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6h8A.png)

[users.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p2Wy.png)

[posts.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8seu.png)

[comments.py file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By5IM.png)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that validation fails is because you are assigning the post author to be a string (e.g., `post1.author = 'Pratik'`) whereas you should assign it to an `User` instance:

```
post1.author = User(firstname='Pratik', lastname='Tester', email='Pratik.Tester@test.it')
```